# Azure API Management and API Versioning

Tags: azure-api-apps, azure-api-management

How does Azure API Management help me manage different versions of my API and re-route selected actions from an old version to a new version of the API?

Comment: You also can use a the versioning schema as query parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve that.

> 1. You can configure your API with a service URL that does not include version segment, like: https://my.api. And then configure
>    version segment on each operation's Rewrite URL template, like have
>    operation with URL template of /resource and Rewrite URL template of
>    /v1/Resource. That way you would be able to change version segment
>    value on each operation separately.
> 2. Or if you'd like to keep "default" version segment in API's service URL then on a selected operations you can set a policy that
>    uses [Set backend service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/7406a8ce-5f9c-4fae-9b0f-e574befb2ee9#SetBackendService) to change backend request path.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-faq#how-do-i-use-api-versioning-in-api-management

Comment: Though you've slightly reworded the original MSDN article, the overall shape is the same. Without citations your answer plagiarises https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-faq