# Should API management version an API if the back end API isn't versioned?

Tags: api, version, azure-api-management

I have a backend API that only has 1 version and is updated monthly.

There is an API management API that sits in front of this backend API.
When the backend API is updated, I use the new swagger file from the backend API to update the API management API.

Should the API mangement API create a new version for every backend release?
Considering the backend API only has 1 version, I think this would mean I would need to update all the previous versions of the API management API to keep it in sync with the new backend API.
Is there any benefit to using versions here I am missing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280231/azure-api-management-and-api-versioning and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/193c102a-b3d3-42c1-8a00-54d36fd9edc9/apim-versioning-with-backend-api-versioning?forum=azureapimgmt

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the purpose of versioning of an api. Let's imagine you have an api that has only one 'v1' version. You realize that you need to create a breaking change that will hurt some of your existing consumers cause they have their code set up for the initial version of your api - 'v1' version. In order to keep them functional you add your breaking change under the 'v2' version, thus you can offer both 'v1' version of your api to existing consumers, and a new 'v2' version for new consumers. What you are describing here is that you every time changing the same 'v1', thus you do not really need a 'v2'. That being said APIM will not do any magic and treat your redeployments as 'v2', 'v3', etc., but it will just replace your existing api 'v1' with whatever your latest code is.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).